# Interpreting WW2 discharge papers codes?

Tags: united-states, military-records, world-war-2

On the World War 2-era WD AGO Form 53-55, which was the four-page honorable discharge form, there is a code or reference in Box 32 (Battles and Campaigns) which on my father-in-law's form says "Rhineland; "GO 33 WD 45 as amended".  What does that phrase refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the post [Meaning of GO 33 WD 45 on a WWII Veteran’s Discharge](http://ww2tribute.blogspot.com/2013/03/meaning-of-go-33-wd-45-on-wwii-veterans.html) on the blog [Tribute to an 82nd Airborne Veteran](http://ww2tribute.blogspot.com/), [Jeff Clark](https://www.blogger.com/profile/03692669731275640003) breaks it down for us as follows:

> GO 33 40 is General Order 33 and General Order 40
>
> WD 45 is War Department 1945
>
> Putting it all together so far, it says:
>
> “General Order 33 and General Order 40 published by the War Department
>   in 1945”.

Clark says that the location usually follows the designation.  He also says that there are two links for the records from 1945, so the "as amended" may refer to the fact that these general orders are in **General Orders 1945 copy 2**.

> General Order 40 amends GO 33, WD 1945 by updating the conditions of
>   the Rome-Arno, and Ardennes campaigns and adds in the Rhineland
>   campaign.
>
> Other General Orders contain information on designated Bronze Service
>   Star campaigns for the rest of the Theaters of Operation in WWII,
>   including the Asiatic-Pacific Theater.

Clark gives the [link to the 1945 General Orders](http://www.benning.army.mil/library/content/Virtual/General%20Orders/GeneralOrders/DAGO1945.pdf) and warns that it is better to right-click to download it, rather than trying to read it in your browser. The document is over 1100 pages.